# Set batch title to file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a way for the title of a batch file to be the same as the file name of the batch file? I am constantly renaming files, so having the title of a batch file be the same as the file name would prevent me from constantly changing the title name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do this by writing a line of code like this.

```
title %~n0
```

The `%0` is the file path for the batch file and the `~n` removes the path and keeps the name.

Hope it works.

Comment: If the file name may contain `&` that wouldn't work... In this rare case one would have to escape it via substring replacements.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm - Could you please provide a working example for my batch filename "Rename this & that & something else.cmd"?